# Google Charts: Bar chart labels are reversed

Tags: google-visualization

I create dinamically a chart for a website. I have a key/value map, I sort the values descending, and then create the url:

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?
  chs=400x200&cht=bhs&chbh=a&chdlp=l&chg=25,0&chma=0,0,0,5&chtt=Chart+test&
  chxr=0,0,8,1&chds=0,8&chxt=t,y&
  chd=t:8,5,3&
  chxl=1:|Label_8|Label_5|Label_3
```

[image: Chart]

The values are set by `chd=t:8,5,3`, and the labels are set by `chxl=1:|Label_8|Label_5|Label_3`. However, in the chart image the labels are reversed.

I searched the documentation, but I didn't get why it is like this. Is it because I didn't set a value correctly, or is this the desired functionality?

I could reverse the label texts in `chxl` from code to be displayed how I want. Is this the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i haven't found any mention about it either, but just made a try with -1 and it works. So use it like:

```
chxl=-1:|Label_8|Label_5|Label_3
```

Comment: It seems that it works with `-1`. It is strange that in the docs it is not specified anything about setting negative values to `chxl`. +1 for you :)